# Expanding sda1 in Ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning

I have a Windows 10 machine hosting a VirtualBox running Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, I ran out of space in my /dev/sda1 partition, so in order to expand it, I (via gparted)

- increased the size of the virtual disk
- deleted my sda2 and sda5 partitions
- resized the sda1
- recreated the sda2 and sda5 partitions

Of course, now my sda5 partition is blank and I'm looking to copy over the files I have from my virtual disk backup. Using dd resulted in my partitions reverting back to their original sizes.

`rsync -a --info=progress2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdb2` 
threw

```
Skipping non-regular file "sdc2"
```

I'm a complete Linux newbie so go easy on me! Where am I going wrong? What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to resize the filesystem after doing the copy, for example doing a resize2fs /dev/sda2 or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is nearly two years old now, but it doesn't have an answer, so I thought I'd answer it anyway.

The files in /dev/ allow access to the raw device data. They don't provide the actual files. For that, you need to `mount` the filesystem. The kernel can then interpret the raw data to get the structure of files, directories, etc. that are stored on the device.

The `/mnt` directory is traditionally used for temporary mounts. Since you're copying from one file system to another, you'll need to create two directories to mount them.

```
cd /mnt
sudo mkdir sdc2
sudo mkdir sdb2
sudo mount /dev/sdc2 /mnt/sdc2
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/sdb2
```

Now, if you look in the folder /mnt/sdc2, you should see your backup files. You can rsync between these two directories to copy the actual files, and `umount` them when you're done.